# In lua, is there forward declaration?

Tags: function, lua, forward-declaration

I wrote quite a lot of functions that call one another, in lua.

Is there, in lua, such a concept as "forward declaration" ?

That would allow me to declare all functions with no implementation and then implement them later. I would then get rid of the order of the functions problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes the visibility goes from top to bottom.
You can declare locals with no value.

```lua
local func -- Forward declaration. `local func = nil` is the same.

local function func2() -- Suppose you can't move this function lower.
    return func() -- used here
end

function func() -- defined here
    return 1
end
```

Comment: For symmetry, declare `func2` as local too.

Comment: Thanks, lhf, that would make more sense

Answer (score 2):

You can define your functions within a table.

```lua
local lib = {}

function lib.func2()
    return lib.func()
end

function lib.func()
    return 1
end
```

This minimizes the specific declaration needed at the top of the file.
It does add a cost of indexing the table which may be relevant and is worth making note of.

This also exposes the functions if you were to return `lib`, which may not be desired if some functions are intended to be "private" to the code in the file. In that case, we can add a second table `private` which will be encapsulated at the local scope:

```lua
local lib = {}
local private = {}

function lib.func2()
    return private.func()
end

function private.func()
    return 1
end

return lib
```

Comment: That's a good way too, for example when you export this as a library. However you should mention calling `lib.func()` will be little bit more expensive when it could be a local. It also can be overridden now. (Edit: it's mentioned already)

Comment: That is a fair point, I hadn't thought about that